# Python:Remove the rest of the words and only keep the first word

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains a column with repeating string. I want to take the first word and remove rest of the words from all the rows I have. I used the unique method as it returns all the unique values and i am looking for only the first occurrence of the words in rows.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re


df=pd.read_csv("file name")

new_data=df['Category'].unique()
changed_data=df['Category'].str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]+', '')
```

This is all I have done,any help on this would be great.

Comment: try `df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')` can you post a sample dataframe

Comment: Can you create same sample data and add expected output? Be free change `df = pd.DataFrame({'Category':['some way','nice', 'be happy', 'nice', 'yop man']})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and select first value of lists by indexing with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) for remove duplicates:

```
changed_data=df['Category'].drop_duplicates().str.split().str[0]
```

Also is possible split by first whitespace only:

```
changed_data=df['Category'].drop_duplicates().str.split(n=1).str[0]
```

If performance is important and no `NaN`s values:

```
changed_data= pd.Series([x.split()[0] for x in df['Category'].drop_duplicates(), 
                         index=df.index)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category':['some way','nice', 'yop yop m', 
                               'be happy', 'nice', 'yop man']})

print (df)
    Category
0   some way
1       nice
2  yop yop m
3   be happy
4       nice
5    yop man
```

First remove duplicates and then get first word:

```
changed_data=df['Category'].drop_duplicates().str.split().str[0]
print (changed_data)
0    some
1    nice
2     yop
3      be
5     yop
Name: Category, dtype: object
```

Or first get first word and then remove duplicates:

```
changed_data=df['Category'].str.split().str[0].drop_duplicates()
print (changed_data)
0    some
1    nice
2     yop
3      be
Name: Category, dtype: object
```